# Why do I get 'Error Internal Server' error while trying POST on Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm trying to test my application api with swagger, while I try POST operation, I get the below error.

Can anyone please explain why am I not able to do this operation? I can for instance run GET operation successfully and get the list of persons from the database.

This is the debugger message.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a

Which refers to this method:

```
  public void InsertPerson(Person person)
  {
        _context.Persons.Add(person);
  }
```

This is what I type in the 'Try it out' box and then execute.

```
   {
  "personId": 2018,
  "firstName": "James",
  "middleName": "string",
  "lastName": "Joey",
  "description": "student",
  "telephone": "22002200",
  "addressId": 2018,
  "address": {
    "addressId": 2018,
    "streetName": "Forest Avenue",
    "houseNumber": "200 B",
    "cityId": 2018,
    "addressType": "private",
    "city": {
      "cityId": 2018,
      "cityName": "ACity",
      "postalcode": "8500",
      "provinceState": "SydDjurslland",
      "country": "SW",
      "addresses": [
        null
      ]
    },
    "personsResidingAtAddress": [
      null
    ]
  },

  "emails": [
    {
      "emailId": 2018,
      "emailAddress": "someone@yahoo.com",
      "emailType": "private",
      "personId": 2018
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this 'bad request':
[image]

In all of my controllers the Get() method shows red. For instance in the below code "GetPerson" is not recognized. Not sure if it has anything to do with this?

```
 // POST: api/People
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostPerson([FromBody] Person person)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Persons.Add(person);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetPerson", new { id = person.PersonId }, person);
    }
```

This is the GetPerson method.

```
    // GET: api/People/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPerson([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var person = await _context.Persons.FindAsync(id);

        if (person == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(person);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: 500 means your Action threw an exception. Should be easy to find in the debugger. Maybe that HTML has something to say when you scroll down but I would go for the Output window in VS.

Comment: I updated my question. See please the debugger exception message.

Comment: Well, it seems like you didn't register your context correctly. Just read a getting started tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Side note: always post code and errormessages as text. Pictures can't be googled.

Comment: Share us the defination for `_context`. You need to register your own `DbContext` like `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));` in `Startup.cs`
`